# bug in laravel 8.4? belongsToMany relationship objects not saved inside transaction

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, transactions, relationship

I have a simple transaction structure and a belongsToMany-relationship between 2 models user and sponsoring. I found out that the relationship data are not saved in the pivot table, when I wrap it inside a transaction.
Without a transaction it works fine.
Is this a zero day bug in laravel (framework v8.40) or does it work somehow different?

My models are defined like this:

```php
class Sponsoring extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_sponsorings');
    }

  // ...
}

class User extends Authenticatable implements HasLocalePreference
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;

    public function sponsorings()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Sponsoring::class, 'user_sponsorings');
    }

  // ...
}
```

My code looks like:

```php
//DB::beginTransaction();

try {
$sponsoring = new Sponsoring();
// ...
$sponsoring->save();

$userIds = [ Auth::user()->id ];
// ...
$sponsoring->users()->sync($userIds);

} catch (\Exception $ex) {
   //DB::rollBack();
   throw new Error('could not save sponsoring: ' . $ex->getMessage());
 }

 //DB::commit();
```

Comment: what is the response youre getting?

Comment: Given that Laravel is currently at 8.51 then try reproducing it on the latest build

Comment: @apokryfos as I could see, it is also in the latest laravel framework version 8.51.

Comment: @JEJ there is not error response. Everything seems to work fine, but inside transactions the relationship data are just not stored to db (or rejected)... :-(
It seems to be an error with the DB::commit method and relationships.

Comment: somehow it works when you wrap the transaction inside
return DB::transaction(function() {
  return $sponsoring;
});

instead of using DB:startTransaction and commit ...
seems to be a bug with transaction levels...